Using linear regression coefficients from table to compute values
I have a file with many variable names and coefficients. The task is to use those variable names and coefficients to create a linear regression formula and apply it to data. Here's a small example:
coefs <- tibble(varname = c("(Intercept)", "dxaids", "abnormal_bun"),
                coef = c(-3.1, 0.1, 0.2))

data <- tibble(dxaids = c(0,0,1), abnormal_bun = c(1,0,0))

The goal is a new column, effectively
data %>% mutate(y = -3.1 + 0.1 * dxaids + 0.2 * abnormal_bun)

What I've done for the time being is manually write out the equation with about 25 variables.
Of course I can write an ugly loop for this, shown below, but is there any cleaner way with tidyverse tools? Perhaps this can be accomplished with a single matrix-vector multiply, but dplyr doesn't seem amenable to matrix operations.
y <- as.numeric(coefs[coefs$varname == "(Intercept)", "coef"])

for (i in 1:nrow(coefs)) {
  varname <- as.character(coefs[i,"varname"])
  coef <- as.numeric(coefs[i,"coef"])
  if (varname != "(Intercept)") 
    y <- y + coef * data[,varname] 
}


Normally you just use predict() along with your model in order to apply the coefficients to new data. Are you explicitly trying to avoid that for some reason?

@MrFlick in this case we are only given the coefficients of a premade model. We don't have the model as an lm object.

You can avoid using a for loop if you use matrix multiplication:
coefs$coef[1] + (as.matrix(data) %*% coefs$coef[-1])
     [,1]
[1,] -2.9
[2,] -3.1
[3,] -3.0

Just make sure columns in data correspond with order in coefs$coef[-1]. Example, if columns in data do not match coef order, then simply you can reorder data using:
data <- data[, 2:1] # note the order is chaged
coefs$coef[1] + (as.matrix (data[, coefs$varname[-1]]) %*% coefs$coef[-1])
     [,1]
[1,] -2.9
[2,] -3.1
[3,] -3.0


Would the data columns be reordered, or the coefs table? I can reorder manually but I'm not sure how to do it. Maybe with some kind of sort.

Ok. I think you had it right with reordering by coefs$varname, but maybe instead of [-1] we can have a column in data of 1s for intercept.

This is assuming (Intercept) will always be the first coef listed, which I think is reasonable.

@qwr that's right, (Intercept] is assumed to be in the first position.

Here's my variant of Jilber Urbina's answer that uses my matrix multiplication idea.
Instead of adding the intercept separately, a new column of 1s is appended to the data for the intercept variable. Then the columns are reordered in the order of coefs$varname so that the matrix multiplication is valid.
# base R
data1 <- data
data1$`(Intercept)` <- 1
drop(as.matrix(data1[,coefs$varname]) %*% coefs$coef)

# tidyverse pipe style
data %>% mutate(`(Intercept)` = 1) %>% select(coefs$varname) %>%
  as.matrix %*% coefs$coef %>% as.numeric

